# iPhone Objective C: How to get a pixel's color of the touched point on an UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, pixel, uitouch

iPhone Objective C: How to get a pixel's color of the touched point on an `UIImageView`, even if the parent `UIView` or itself is being rotated by the `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` function?

Will the view property of the UITouch still correctly return the correct pixel of the touched point even if the `UIView`/`UIImageView` is being scaled and rotated?

Many thanks for reading

edited: Thanks for the answer & comments, but sorry I still don't know how to get the X,Y point of the scaled/rotated image from the touch event, and then extract the color from it. Would anyone mind to help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A [quick google search](http://tinyurl.com/mxoxto) has revealed some promising leads:

- [Getting Pixel data from a CGImage object](http://developer.apple.com/qa/qa2007/qa1509.html)
- [Another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125)
- [What color is my pixel?](http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/)

Comment: thanks a lot for the link. But I'm still wondering whether these all will still work or not if the UIView is being scaled and rotated.

Comment: best to find out, is to try, try again! i used the first option in some of my own work!

Comment: Sorry I still don't know how to get the X,Y point of the scaled/rotated image from the touch event, and then extract the color from it. Would anyone mind to help?

Comment: By reading the provided links, I can't find any clues on how to extract the X,Y point of the scaled/rotated image from the touch point.