# I want to build a UIView which helps the user to choose a color from a pattern

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

[image]

Hi,

I want to add this image and make the user choose a color from the image, can it be done wisely, is there any open source project which does that?

Thanks

Comment: Quick search:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285621/iphone-objective-c-how-to-get-a-pixels-color-of-the-touched-point-on-an-uiimag

Comment: Thank you very much box86rowh, the link answered my question perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

While getting the color of a pixel at a particular point is easy (and answers to that are there in the first comment on the question), I just wanted to offer that a user might expect a magnifying glass or some UI that helps them pick the color - people aren't going to be able to tap exactly on the color they want on the iPhone since the color wheel is likely to be rather small.