# how to check UIView and UIImageView is touched or not in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

I have One `UIView` and one **Draggable** `UIImageView`.
Background color of `UIView` is **green**.

When I will drag the image, `UIImageView` will touch `UIView`.
When I drag the image over `UIView` the colour of `UIView` should become **red**.

**How to check that `UIImageView` reached over `UIView` ?**

Comment: For dragging `UIImageView`, are you using pangesture or touches move method????

Comment: @NishaSingh i add code which changed color of yourView's backcolor when UIImageView is moved inside of yourView'frame otherwise its set clearColor,you can set any color when that image move outside of that yourView :)

Answer (score 8):

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{   
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(imageview.frame, view.frame)) {
        view.backgroundColor=[UIColor redcolor];
    }
}
```

Comment: Careful, I've been down voted numerous times for not adding an explanation to the code. Add a summary of what's happening for a complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can check that with `touchesBegan` method like bellow...

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
      ///This is UIImageView
    }
    else if([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) 
    {
      ///This is UIView
    }
}
```

and when you move the `UIImageView` at that time its change the backGroundColor of `UIView` with bellow code...

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *tap = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint pointToMove = [tap locationInView:self.view];
    if([tap.view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
        UIImageView *tempImage=(UIImageView *) tap.view;
        if ([yourView pointInside:pointToMove withEvent:event])
        {
            [yourView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        }
        else{
            [yourView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];//set backcolor which you want when `UIImageView` move outside of yourView 
        }
    }
}
```

Also For Moving see the answer from this link [Move UIImage only inside of another UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199657/move-uiimage-only-inside-of-another-uiimage)

Comment: You are not checking if the `UIImageView` intersects with `UIView`.

Comment: @Mar0ux what you want to say?? and also if you know best answer then post your answer .. here whats wrong?? its working and i test it..

Comment: Try this: touch the `UIImageView` from top left corner and drag it such that `UIView`'s top left touches `UIImageView`'s bottom right. See [Ashini's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16297553/440060) for how it should be done.

Comment: i completed it and its working after that i most that second part of code ... its working for me dude...

Comment: Hi @ParasJoshi: I am implementing LongGestureRecognizer. I want to change the color of a specific portion which user touches via long gesture. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: I can show you my code also if you can come in chat.

Answer (score 0):

By using `UIPanGestureRecognizer`

```
- (void)onDraggingLetter:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGR {

 CGPoint translation = [panGR translationInView:self.view];

    if (panGR.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

    } else if (panGR.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {  

        CGRect _rect = panGR.view.frame;
        _rect.origin.x = dragPoint.x + translation.x;
        _rect.origin.y = dragPoint.y + translation.y;
        panGR.view.frame = _rect;

         if (CGRectIntersectsRect(panGR.view.frame, greenView.frame)) {

               greenView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
         }

    } else if (panGR.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    }
}
```